# Orthonormal system $\{ e_n(t)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is complete $\Leftrightarrow$ $k(t,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{|e_n(t)|^2}, \forall t \in \Omega$

Tags: functional-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I want to prove that, in a RKHS (Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space), being k(t,s) its reproducing kernel:

Orthonormal system $\{ e_n(t)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is complete $\Leftrightarrow$ $k(t,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{|e_n(t)|^2}, \forall t \in \Omega$.

So far, I've proved that if $\{ e_n(t)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is complete, then it is an orthonormal basis, and the Parseval identity applies, giving:

$$||k_t||^2 = k(t,t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|\langle k_t,e_n\rangle|^2}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|\langle e_n,k_t\rangle|^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|e_n(t)|^2}.$$

The last identity is given by the reproducing property.

My problem is in the converse proof: given $k(t,t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{|e_n(t)|^2}, \forall t \in \Omega \Rightarrow \{ e_n(t)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is complete.

Comment: What is the definition of reproducing kernel ?

Comment: A reproducing kernel is a Linear form $k: \Omega \times \Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}: k(t,s) := \langle k_s,k_t \rangle = k_s (t), \ \ (t,s) \in \Omega $. By the Riesz Representation Theorem, there is an element $k_t$ in $\mathcal{H}$, such that $f(t) = \langle f, k_t \rangle$ for all $f \in \mathcal{H}$.